# Template file is wrapping sub-routes

Tags: javascript, next.js, app-router

I am using Next v13.5.4 with the new App router.

[image: folder structure]

The `products/template.tsx` is being applied in the `products/page.tsx` route, but also in the `products/[id]/page.tsx` sub-route, even though it shouldn't, according to the official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/template).

I have tried changing `template` for `layout` and deleting the `.next` folder, because I thought cache could have been causing it, but with no luck.

Is there something I am not seeing?